# Cannot set custom discriminator convention for object

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using the MongoDB C# driver (2.4.4) for .NET Core.
I would like to register a custom discriminator convention for all objects:

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterDiscriminatorConvention(typeof(object), new CustomDiscriminatorConvention());
```

Unfortunately, my custom discriminator convention is not being called by the serializer. I've checked the BSON serializer source code, and it looks like the default hierarchical discriminator convention is always used in this case.

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Bson/Serialization/BsonSerializer.cs (lines 393-408):

```
// inherit the discriminator convention from the closest parent (that isn't object) that has one
// otherwise default to the standard hierarchical convention
Type parentType = type.GetTypeInfo().BaseType;
while (convention == null)
{
    if (parentType == typeof(object))
    {
        convention = StandardDiscriminatorConvention.Hierarchical;
        break;
    }
    if (__discriminatorConventions.TryGetValue(parentType, out convention))
    {
        break;
    }
    parentType = parentType.GetTypeInfo().BaseType;
}
```

If the two if-statements in the loop would be reversed, my custom convention would be found and used instead. Why would the serializer not check for custom object discriminator conventions first?

Is there another way of registering an object discriminator convention? Or overriding the default convention? Do I need to write a custom serializer? That seems like overkill for a feature that is supposed to be supported by the default serializer in the first place.

Please note that this is part of a library where I do not know at design time which class types will be persisted to the database. Therefore I cannot register the convention for more specific types.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround we're using is registering an ordinary convention that sets the discriminators to what we want them to be:

```
public class CustomDiscriminatorConvention : ConventionBase, IClassMapConvention
{
    public void Apply(BsonClassMap classMap)
    {
        Type type = classMap.ClassType;
        if (type.IsClass
            && type != typeof(string)
            && type != typeof(object)
            && !type.IsAbstract)
        {
            classMap.SetDiscriminator(GetCustomDiscriminatorFor(type));
        }
    }
}
```

To register conventions use something like the following on your app startup:

```
var conventions = new ConventionPack { new CustomDiscriminatorConvention(), ... };
ConventionRegistry.Register("Custom conventions", conventions, t => true);
```